# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'.You may need to add middleware to your store - in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to fetch products from firebase and also I have already installed redux-thunk to handle promises and using middleware in my store.

Error: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions. See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware and https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware for examples.

```
import Product from "../../models/Product";

export const DELETE_PRODUCT = "DELETE_PRODUCT";
export const CREATE_PRODUCT = "CREATE_PRODUCT";
export const UPDATE_PRODUCT = "UPDATE_PRODUCT";
export const SET_PRODUCT = "SET_PRODUCT";

export const fetchProducts = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://shopping-app-6xxx8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json"
  );
  const resData = await response.json();
  const loadedProducts = [];

  for (const key in resData) {
    loadedProducts.push(
      new Product(
        key,
        "u1",
        resData[key].title,
        resData[key].imageUrl,
        resData[key].description,
        resData[key].price
      )
    );
  }
  dispatch({ type: SET_PRODUCT, products: loadedProducts });
};

export const deleteProduct = (productId) => {
  return { type: DELETE_PRODUCT, pid: productId };
};

export const createProduct = (title, description, imageUrl, price) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://shopping-app-62e38-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          title,
          description,
          imageUrl,
          price,
        }),
      }
    );
    const resData = await response.json();

    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_PRODUCT,
      productData: {
        id: resData.name,
        title,
        description,
        imageUrl,
        price,
      },
    });
  };
};

export const updateProduct = (id, title, description, imageUrl) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_PRODUCT,
    pid: id,
    productData: { title, description, imageUrl },
  };
};
```

Comment: Try [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started#using-create-react-app).

Comment: `async` functions return a promise. `await` unwraps that promise.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [thunks](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) this design is part of the [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) used in [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk).